# Web Deploy Package in VS 2012 publish sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, publish, web-deployment

I've used publish option for my web application project 
I selected web deployment package then finish filling the needed publish profile data and everything goes right 
But when it comes to database no scripts are generated : I'm using package/publish sql tab and i entered the needed data for my source database and I selected to get data and schema and check auto 
just like this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576376%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and package/publish SQL tab in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) 
but no scripts are generated and no databases are created after deploying.
I've used the same steps with VS 2010 and everything works fine !
are there any any consideration I should have while using VS 2012 with SQL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the **Configuration**? Maybe you setup deployment for the 'Debug' Configuration.